# Generated query from memory database is not accurate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have an entity in containing :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pictures")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class PictureEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;

@Column
private String path;

@Column(name = "thumb_path")
private String thumbPath;

@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

@Column(name = "creation_utc")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creationTimeUtc;

@Column(name = "creation_local")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creationTimeLocal;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", updatable = true, insertable = true)
private ProjectEntity project;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = true, insertable = true)
private UserEntity user;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "picture", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ProcessedPictureEntity processedPicture;

public enum Status {
    VALIDATED,
    PROCESSED,
    REJECTED,
    WAITING_VALIDATION
}

}
```

When I call a save with H2 database, it saves the "project_id" field too. 
But if I use mysql, the generated query isn't the same, project is not saved (which I think is the correct behavior). 
**I want the test with H2 to crash if updatable/insertable on project_id are false.**

How can I correct this ?

Comment: So how do you want to have relation without a foreigh key that specifies the connection between 2 entities in different tables(project_id)?

Comment: I want this to be  updatable = true that's not the point, I just want my test to crash if updatable = true. A member of my team put this on the entity, the test didn't crash and of course a big error arised on production... I want this to not happen again.

Comment: To update this you have to 1) SELECT parent from table 2) eg create new childs 3) selectedParent.setProject(newChild) 3) save changes (if not done automatically)

Comment: How does ProjectEntity  look like?

Comment: Edit with all entity

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have two problems:

1. H2 and MySQL behave differently causing bugs to slip through your tests.
2. You want to test if a certain field got updated.

For 1.: I recommend Testcontainers. It allows you to run tests with an actual MySQL database (or any other database that you can get a docker image for).
This will make your integration tests way more valuable.

For 2.: Execute whatever code you suspect does the update in question and then check if the field got changed. 
Make sure the changes get flushed which is a common cause of tests not behaving as on things. 
For checking for changes I recommend Springs `JdbcTemplate` for easily executing queries.

Comment: Yes, sadly H2 is just a dream that cannot solve this it seems. Will switch on Testcontainers if that behave completely like in real case. Thank you !